# How to set the hmacsha1 key to hex in PHP?

Tags: php, hmacsha1

I'm able to successfully get a HMAC SHA1 signature key using the following code:

```
echo hash_hmac('sha1','office:fred','AA381AC5E4298C23B3B3333333333333333333');
```

which yields:

```
5e50e6458b0cdc7ee534967d113a9deffe6740d0
```

However, the place I am working with is expecting this instead:

```
46abe81345b1da2f1a330bba3d6254e110cd9ad8
```

I tried an [online tool](http://caligatio.github.com/jsSHA/) and it appears that the difference between the two is that the one the people I am working with are expecting a HEX type signature key.

Is there something I need to add to my PHP in order to output the HEX type?

Comment: What are the differences between the two systems? I suggest you add the two PHP versions to your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to convert the hexadecimal string to binary data before passing it into hash_hmac:

```
var_dump(hash_hmac("sha1", "office:fred", pack("H*", "AA381AC5E4298C23B3B3333333333333333333")));
```

Outputs `46abe81345b1da2f1a330bba3d6254e110cd9ad8` as expected.